# Call Oracle function in package in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I just begin with Oracle. I read lot of post and ... I don't find where is my mistake
I've a function in package PKG_GETOBJ

```
FUNCTION GetNewID(sReference IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
IS
NewCtpVal   NUMBER;
BEGIN
 UPDATE TABLE set VALUE = (VALUE + 1) WHERE Field= sReference RETURN VALUE INTO NewCtpVal;
 return NewCtpVal;
END;
```

and here how I try to call it:

```
 Dim con As OracleConnection = GetConnexion()
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand With {.Connection = con}
    'PKG_GETOBJ.GETNEWID('ID_OBJECT');'Sample calling in SQL with success
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter With {.ParameterName = "sReference", .OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, .Value = "ID_OBJECT", .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input})
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter With {.ParameterName = "NewCtpVal", .OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Double, .Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue})
    cmd.CommandText = "PKG_GETOBJ.GETNEWID"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    For Each p As OracleParameter In cmd.Parameters
        HelperJournal.WriteEntry("PKG_GETOBJ " & p.ParameterName, If(p.Value Is Nothing, "null", p.Value.ToString))'Write in file
    Next
    con.Close()
    con.Dispose()
```

My problem is NewCtpVal is empty, then I Database I've a number value...

Comment: First thing, is the update portion of that function being created?  Next, been a while since I've done this myself, what happens if you drop the NewCtpVal param and call Dim retVal = cmd.ExecuteScaler() rather than ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: thanks for the response. The update function is already in use since several years. But it's first time trying to access by vb.net.  I try your suggestion and say what else

Comment: Bad luck that say GETNEWID is not a procedure....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally I found a way...

```
  Public Function GetNewId() As Decimal
    Dim retval
    Using con As OracleConnection = GetConnexion(),
     cmd As New OracleCommand With {.Connection = con}
        cmd.CommandText = "PKG_GETOBJ.GETNEWID"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Dim prm = New OracleParameter("returnvalue", OracleDbType.Decimal)
        prm.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prm)

        Dim prm1 = New OracleParameter("sReference", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
        prm1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        prm1.Value = "ID_OBJECT"
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prm1)

        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        retval = cmd.Parameters("returnvalue").Value.ToString
    End Using
    Return retval
End Function
```